# How to use GetAsync or PostAsync in RestSharp

Tags: c#, restsharp

I can't find any examples of using `GetAsync` or `PostAsync` methods. I'm try to implement it with:

```
private static Task<IRestResponse> GetResultAsync(RestClient client, RestRequest request)
{
    var taskSource = new TaskCompletionSource<IRestResponse>();
    client.GetAsync(request, response =>
    {
        taskSource.SetResult(response);
    });
    return taskSource.Task;
}
```

and I get an error, because I don't know what must be passed as `RestRequestAsyncHandle` argument:

> Delegate 'Action < IRestResponse, RestRequestAsyncHandle>' does not take 1
>   arguments

Can somebody tell me what should be passed as `RestRequestAsyncHandle`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm struggling to find anything specific in the documentation, but it looks like your problem is more that you're expecting to have to provide a `RestRequestAsyncHandle`. Instead, it looks like you need to "take" one in your callback. e.g:

```
client.GetAsync(request, (response, handle) =>
{
    taskSource.SetResult(response);
});
```

The [code](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/RestRequestAsyncHandle.cs) for `RestRequestAsyncHandle` shows that it contains an `Abort` function that you could call from within your handler, if needed.

I can't vouch for whether this is the correct way to use async in RestSharp, but I think this addresses your specific error. @Fildor's answer and comment below suggest a more correct approach to the async stuff as a whole.

Comment: That would be correct, *but*: Mixing TAP and the good ol' Async is not much of a good idea. RestClient provides a TAP API - so why not use it?

Comment: @Fildor I agree completely.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to walk the Task-based async path, then do it all the way:

```
private static Task<IRestResponse> GetResultAsync(RestClient client, RestRequest request)
{
    return client.ExecuteGetAsync(request);
}
```

Kirk gave a good explanation what you missed about the AsyncHandle in your approach, so I won't repeat it here.

Looking at the code on github, they seem to actually have done "under the hood", what you tried. So I wouldn't reinvent the wheel.